# Binomial model with random effects. Also Plot that

Tags: r, regression, logistic, biostatistics

I'm looking to build a binomial model in R for a fascinating experiment involving flower pollination at various temperatures. In this experiment, plants exhibit a dynamic range of flowers and floral stems. Some plants even boast different floral stems, each with a varying number of flowers.

As bees work their magic and successfully pollinate these flowers, they transform into fruits. My curiosity leads me to explore whether the probability of pollination, or the generation of fruits, is influenced by temperature. I'd love to delve deeper into this and hear your thoughts on the matter!

For this, I use the `glmer` function from the `lme4` package.

Now, I'll describe how my database is structured.

```r
library(Matrix)
library(lme4)

temperature <- rep(seq(25, length.out = 8), each = 5)

flowers <- c(7,8,14,9,9,14,10,5,7,8,13,10,10,9,7,14,10,3,11,8,6,8,6,7,7,4,12,9,6,13,10,8,12,12,11,11,11,9,8,8)

fruits <- c(1,0,5,0,0 ,3 ,2 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,3 ,0 ,5 ,3 ,1 ,2 ,0 ,4 ,0 ,5 ,0 ,6 ,7 ,7 ,0 ,5 ,8 ,4 ,1 ,2 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,9 ,7 ,3 ,5 ,0 ,8)

ID <-  c("plant 1",  "plant 2",  "plant 3",  "plant 3",  "plant 3",
         "plant 4",  "plant 4",  "plant 5",  "plant 5",  "plant 6",
         "plant 7",  "plant 8", "plant 9",  "plant 10", "plant 10", 
         "plant 11",  "plant 11",  "plant 11","plant 12","plant 12",
         "plant 13",  "plant 13", "plant 14", "plant 14","plant 14",
         "plant 15","plant 15",  "plant 16", "plant 16", "plant 16",
         "plant 17", "plant 17", "plant 18","plant 18", "plant 19",
         "plant 20", "plant 20", "plant 21", "plant 21","plant 22")

spike <- c(1,1,1,2,3,
           1,2,1,2,1,
           1,1,1,1,2,
           1,2,3,1,2,
           1,2,1,2,3,
           1,2,1,2,3,
           1,2,1,2,1,
           1,2,1,2,1)

df_flowers <- data.frame(temperature, flowers, fruits, ID, spike)
```

As you can see, the variable "spike" simply indicates, when applicable, the number corresponding to each floral stem. Since the floral stem depends on the same flower, I believe it should be nested within each plant.

As mentioned in some literature, one can use the `cbind` function to create a small matrix with proportions. This is done as follows:

```r
response2 <- cbind(df_flowers$flowers, df_flowers$flowers - 
                                       df_flowers$fruits)
```

Now, let's create the models, starting with the simplest one, which does not consider the plant ID as a random effect.

```r
model1 <- glm(response2 ~ temperature, family = binomial, 
              data = df_flowers)
summary(model1)
```

We can observe that the probability of pollination is indeed influenced by temperature. However, this analysis doesn't account for the previously described implications.

Hence, we'll create a second model, incorporating the plant ID as a random variable:

```r
model2 <- glmer(response2 ~ temperature + (1|ID), family =  binomial, 
                data = df_flowers)
summary(model2)
```

I think we've progressed quite well up to this point, and I would appreciate your support at this stage. I'm not sure if I did the statistically correct thing by nesting 'spike.' It's a doubt I have about whether this is correct.

```
model3 <- glmer(response2 ~ temperature + (1|ID/spike), 
                family =  binomial, data = df_flowers)
summary(model3)
```

Finally, as a last question, I would like your help in creating a plot, preferably with ggplot2, of my model. Since we found that temperature significantly affects the probability of pollination.

I've had trouble specifically with plotting this because, as far as I know, using the binomial family in plots requires a matrix of 1s and 0s.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `cbind(fruits, flowers - fruits)`?